# Adding components to the correct game object

Tags: unity, gameobject

I created a `MonoBehaviour` with a `LineReader`, to draw multiple lines. I'm attaching radius indicators for when I debug enemies in my game.

The circle is rendered around my Enemy as expected; however, I've noticed that the `LineRenderer` is attached to my `Enemy` game object. It seems like `AddComponent` binds to the parent `gameObject`, which in this case is `Enemy`.

Is there any way to attach the `LineRenderer` to my `RangeIndicator` instance?

---

This is my `Enemy` script:

```
[System.Serializable]
public struct RangeIndicatorData
{
    public Color RangeColor;
    public float Radius;
    public string Name;
}

public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour, IMovable, ITargetable 
{
    public RangeIndicatorData[] RangeIndicators;
    public bool DisplayRangeIndicators = true;

    void Start()
    {   
        if(DisplayRangeIndicators)
        {
            for(uint i = 0; i < RangeIndicators.Length; i++)
            {
                gameObject.AddComponent<RadiusRenderer>();
            }
        }
    }

    void Update() 
    {
        if(DisplayRangeIndicators)
        {
            RadiusRenderer[] renderers = gameObject.GetComponents<RadiusRenderer>();

            int i = 0;
            foreach(RadiusRenderer renderer in renderers)
            {
                RangeIndicatorData indicator = RangeIndicators[i];
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

This is my `RadiusRenderer` class:

```
public class RadiusRenderer : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public LineRenderer lr;

    public void RenderPoints(float radius, Color32 c1, Color32 c2)
    {
        lr = gameObject.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();

        if(lr == null) 
        {
            lr = (LineRenderer)gameObject.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
        }

        // ...

    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, I apologise for the poor code quality, I've only been using Unity and experimenting with game dev for the last couple of days.  In my head I see it as I'm adding multiple `RadiusRenderer` components as a child to `Enemy` and then I want to bind a `LineRenderer` to each `RadiusRenderer` instance so that I can have multiple lines drawn, the way I see the code at the moment that's actually what I'd expect to happen, sorry again if I've totally foobarred this! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gameObject` points to the game object of which `this` instance of the script is attached to. In short, your adding `LineRenderer` to the game object associated with the `RadiusRenderer` script, which you have added to the game object associated with the `Enemy` script. There is no parent association, in this context, except for the association you provide in your logic.

---

The simplest solution is to create a hard reference to the game object for which you wish to attach your component. You can not necessarily do this directly from your `RadiusRenderer` script, as you may instantiate it by code, and thus do not have access to that instance via the Inspector.

Instead, provide the reference in `Enemy`, and pass it to `RadiusRenderer`. Ensure the instances that *are* created in the Inspector have their `rangeIndicatorInstance` set via the Inspector, too.

```
public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    // link this reference up via the Inspector.
    public GameObject rangeIndicatorInstance;

    void Start()
    {   
        if(DisplayRangeIndicators)
        {
            for(uint i = 0; i < RangeIndicators.Length; i++)
            {
                // We need to make reference to each instance..
                RadiusRenderer radiusRenderer 
                    = gameObject.AddComponent<RadiusRenderer>();
                // so we can pass our reference.
                radiusRenderer.rangeIndicatorInstance = rangeIndicatorInstance;
            }
        }
    }
}

public class RadiusRenderer : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public GameObject rangeIndicatorInstance;

    public void RenderPoints(float radius, Color32 c1, Color32 c2)
    {
        // Now, all we have to do is add the component to our range indicator 
        // game object, instead of our radius renderer game object.
        lr = rangeIndicatorInstance.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();

        if(lr == null) 
        {  
            lr = (LineRenderer)rangeIndicatorInstance.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this makes so much more sense, thank-you!